# choose file names in R satisfying some criteria

Tags: r

I store many files in a directory but I only need some of them. The files I need all contain `transcript_counts` so that I am thinking if `R` has a function that help me pick up those file names with `transcript_counts`. For example, by using `dir()` I can see a list of file names:

```
 [1] "xx1_sequence_alignment.csv"  
 [2] "xx2_sequence_transcript_counts.csv"
 [3] "xx3_sequence_alignment.csv"  
 [4] "xx4_sequence_transcript_counts.csv"
 [5] "xx5_sequence_alignment.csv"
```

Now I want to have a list containing only `xx2_sequence_transcript_counts.csv`, `xx4_sequence_transcript_counts.csv` and so on with `transcript_counts` as identifiers. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `pattern` argument

```
dir(pattern="transcript_counts")
```

From `?dir`

> pattern: an optional regular expression. Only file names which match the regular expression will be returned.

---

If you already have a character vector you can use `grep` to get the elements you want.

```
x <- dir()
grep("transcript_counts", x, value=TRUE)
```

Comment: BTW, if I have a list of file names and hope to find those file with a particular pattern, how can I do that using any R functions? Thanks!

Comment: @alittleboy, You're welcome.  Don't forget to look at `?dir` and `?grep` to see what other arguments are available to you.